# Why is HAProxy unable to load certificates generated by letsencrypt?

Tags: ssl-certificate, haproxy, lets-encrypt

HAProxy is unable to load .pem files generated by [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), why is this?

The error I'm seeing is:

```
parsing [/haproxy.cfg:37] : 'bind :443' : unable to load SSL private key from PEM file '/certs/cert0.pem'.
```

The contents of the PEM file is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Your PEM file don't contain private key, so the error is expected.

Comment: @CryptoGuy Thanks, I realized in the meantime, as I looked at which other files letsencrypt generated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that I was using the fullchain.pem file generated by letsencrypt. Instead, one should concatenate it together with 'privkey.pem' (also generated by letsencrypt) into a single .pem file.

Comment: In case this answer doesn't solve your problem, you might want to try to remove the passphrase from the private key. It solved the problem for me.

To remove the password, try
'openssl rsa -in [PRIVATE_KEY_FILE] -out nopassphrase.key'

Comment: Actionable, copy and paste friendly command line:
`cat cert.pem privkey.pem > haproxy_cert.pem`

Comment: Concatenating is the solution, but it needs to be automated, otherwise there is no point in automating renewals.

Answer (score 4):

I could only fix this by using **cert.pem** instead of **fullchain.pem** when concatenating.

```
cat cert.pem key.pem > haproxy_cert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-ssl-termination/:

```
frontend www.mysite.com
bind 10.0.0.3:80
bind 10.0.0.3:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.pem
default_backend web_servers
```

> The ssl parameter enables SSL termination for this listener. The **crt** parameter identifies the location of the PEM-formatted SSL certificate.
>
> This certificate should contain both **the public certificate** and **private key**.

To be honest, according with my experience on deploying HA Proxy with TLS/SSL end-to-end with minimum 2 nodes as Backend servers, this statement is somewhat true. In fact, HA Proxy requires `fullchain.pem` (instead of cert.pem) + `privkey.pem` as a single file. Not using `fullchain.pem` will lead to messages on Systemd like `unable to load cert` or things like that.

In a nutshell, **you shall do**:

```
$ cat fullchain.pem privkey.pem > /etc/haproxy/mydomain_certs/mydomain.pem
```

And not:

```
$ cat cert.pem privkey.pem > /etc/haproxy/mydomain_certs/mydomain.pem
```

This [artile](https://serversforhackers.com/c/letsencrypt-with-haproxy) has a valuable example.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the issue that I encountered. The `cat` command generated concatenated the files without a newline between them. I manually inserted a new line (using `vim`) and it worked.

Also in my case I got three files from the registrar: crt, ca-bundle, and p7b. I just want to add that all I needed was the private key file and the crt file (so ca-bundle and p7b were not used).